# Conditional statements: one of requirements must be met, not all

Tags: java, spring

I have a class which is also a Spring component.

```
@Component
public class ComponentClass {
    // code
}
```

I want it to be created only on some conditions. For example, **at least ONE** of these conditions must be met:

- `BeanA` must exist
- `BeanB` must exist
- profile `foo` must be set

For example, `@ConditionalOnBean({BeanA.class, BeanB.class})` does not do what I want as it means both of these beans must exist.

Comment: @OleV.V. at least one :)

Comment: You need an OR condition, not an AND condition.

Comment: I have no experience with Spring, so this is a long shot, but have you tried specifying the annotation multiple times?@ConditionalOnBean({BeanA.class}) @ConditionalOnBean({BeanB.class})

Comment: @SolarMike not sure what you mean. Did I specify somewhere explicitly the 'AND' condition?

Comment: You may need a custom annotation. An example here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-conditional-annotations#defining-custom-conditions

Comment: @ESipalis Yes. That would not compile as `@ConditionalOnBean` is not a repeatable annotation.

Comment: You can probably use https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/AnyNestedCondition.html

Answer (score 2):

As per suggestions of [@lealceldeiro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5640649/lealceldeiro), [@Rob Spoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180351/rob-spoor) and [@Solar Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4961700/solar-mike) in the comments to the post, custom annotation based on OR (not AND) conditions was the correct solution.

My solution is this class that extends `AnyNestedCondition`:

```
public class ConditionalOnMyTerms extends AnyNestedCondition {

    ConditionalOnMyTerms() {
        super(ConfigurationPhase.REGISTER_BEAN);
    }

    @ConditionalOnBean(com.example.BeanA.class)
    static class BeanA {}

    @ConditionalOnBean(com.example.BeanB.class)
    static class BeanB {}

    @Profile("foo")
    static class fooProfile {}
}
```